# Can not get the expected plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I got an example from a textbook for plotting by python

What I expected is [image: 1]

But I can't achieve it. I got the following.

[image: 2]

My code:

```
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

# Create figure for plotting
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
xs = []
ys = []


 # This function is called periodically from FuncAnimation
def animate (i , xs , ys ) :

    tempc = round(np.random.random(), 2)

 # Add x and y to lists
    xs.append(dt.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f'))
    ys.append(tempc)

 # Limit x and y lists to 20 items
    xs = xs [-20:]
    ys = ys [-20:]

 # Draw x and y lists
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(xs, ys)

 # Format plot
    plt.xticks(rotation =45, ha='right')
    plt.subplots_adjust( bottom=0.30)
    plt.title(' Temperature Data ' )
    plt.ylabel( ' Temperature ( deg C) ' )

 # Set up plot to call animate( ) function periodically
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig , animate , fargs=(xs , ys ) ,
    interval =1000)
plt.show( )
```

Should I add a for loop something like?

Comment: Your code works for me. What environment are you using? What version of matplotlib, what backend?

Comment: I don't know. I just downloaded Anaconda(Windows) and I pasted the code in the Spyder(Python 3.8) Window then run it.

Comment: matplotlib: 3.2.2,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```

Try this:

```
#generate random number for temp
tempc = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(60,))

#generate one minute timestamp
now = dt.datetime.now()
delta = timedelta(seconds=1)

for i in range(60):
    xs.append(now.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
    now += delta

xs = np.array(xs)
ys = np.array(tempc)
```

[image]